# JButton hover effect animation. Changing opacity by Mouse Listener

Tags: java, swing, animation, jbutton, rollover

I'd like to do JButton with nice transition effect. I write a class which extend by JButton and add to it custom MouseAdapter. It almost works, but if opacity should have 0 my one BufferedImage don't vanish.

Here my all source code:

```
public class ImageHoverButton extends JButton {

    public class MouseListener extends MouseAdapter
      {
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent me)
        {
          new Thread(new Runnable()
          {
            public void run()
            {
              for (float i = 1f; i >= 0f; i -= .03f)
              {
                setOpacity(i);
                try
                {
                  Thread.sleep(10);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                }
              }
            }
          }).start();
        }

        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent me)
        {
          new Thread(new Runnable()
          {
            public void run()
            {
              for (float i = 0f; i <= 1f; i += .03f)
              {
                  setOpacity(i);
                try
                {
                  Thread.sleep(10);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                }
              }
            }
          }).start();
        }

        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me)
        {
          new Thread(new Runnable()
          {
            public void run()
            {
              for (float i = 1f; i >= 0.6f; i -= .1f)
              {
                  setOpacity(i);
                try
                {
                  Thread.sleep(1);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                }
              }
            }
          }).start();
        }
      }


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private BufferedImage imgBottom;
    private BufferedImage imgHover;
    private BufferedImage imgHoverRGB;

    // filter to imgInActive
    float[] scales = { 1f, 1f, 1f, 0f};
    float[] offsets = new float[4];
    RescaleOp rop = new RescaleOp(scales, offsets, null);

    /**
     * Constructor for image path 
     * @param img
     * @param x
     * @param y
     */

    public ImageHoverButton(String imgBottomPath, String imgHoverPath, int x, int y) {

        try {
            this.imgBottom = ImageIO.read(new File(imgBottomPath));
            this.imgHover = ImageIO.read(new File(imgHoverPath));


            imgHoverRGB = new BufferedImage(imgHover.getWidth(null), 
                                            imgHover.getHeight(null), 
                                            BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
            Graphics g = imgHoverRGB.getGraphics();
            g.drawImage(imgHover, 0, 0, null);

        } catch (IOException e) {
        } 
        this.setBounds(x, y, imgBottom.getWidth() + 40 , imgBottom.getHeight() + 50);
        addMouseListener(new MouseListener());
        setOpacity(0f);
        setOpaque(false);
        setBorderPainted(false);
        setRolloverEnabled(false);
        setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        setLayout(null);



    }

    public void setOpacity(float opacity) {
        scales[3] = opacity;
        rop = new RescaleOp(scales, offsets, null);
        repaint();
    }

     public void paint(Graphics g) {
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
            g2d.drawImage(imgBottom, 50, 50, null);
            g2d.drawImage(imgHoverRGB, rop, 0, 0);
     }

}
```

Have any idea how to improve this?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example).

Comment: I don't know if it makes any differnece, but the minimal opacity value is only 0.01

Answer (score 2):

I'm not so familiar with `RescaleOp`, and can't remember having used this before. But it seems like the results of applying it in this case are somewhat unexpected.

As an alternative, you might consider an `AlphaComposite`. The minimum modification that is necessary to achieve the desired effect would then be to change the line

```
g2d.drawImage(imgHoverRGB, rop, 0, 0);
```

to

```
g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(
    AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, scales[3]));
g2d.drawImage(imgHoverRGB, 0, 0, null);
```

However, there are several other issues with the code:

- don't override `paint`. Instead, override `paintComponent`
- don't call `setBounds` on a component (particlularly not in a constructor). The placement should be done by a layout manager
- don't swallow Exceptions silently
- don't load the images in the constructor of the button
- implement `getPreferredSize` properly
- don't spawn hundreds of threads due to mouse movement. (When you quickly move the mouse in and out, you'll have several threads running - some of them increasing the opacity, and some of them decreasing the opacity)

I created an example showing one possible approach: It contains an `OpacityAnimator` that allows a transition between two opacities, with a predefined delay in milliseconds. This animator is used to increase the opacity of the foreground image when the button is hovered with the mouse, and to decrease it when the mouse leaves the button.

(Note that this could be generalized further, and there are many possible "configuration settings" (like the transition delay) that could be exposed, but this is just intended as an example)

```
import java.awt.AlphaComposite;
import java.awt.Cursor;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class HoverButtonTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                try
                {
                    createAndShowGUI();
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() throws IOException
    {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        BufferedImage backgroundImage = loadImage("background.png");
        BufferedImage foregroundImage = loadImage("foreground.png");
        f.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        f.getContentPane().add(
            new ImageHoverButton(backgroundImage, foregroundImage));

        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static BufferedImage loadImage(String path) throws IOException
    {
        return convertToARGB(ImageIO.read(new File(path)));
    }

    public static BufferedImage convertToARGB(BufferedImage image)
    {
        BufferedImage newImage = new BufferedImage(image.getWidth(),
            image.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D g = newImage.createGraphics();
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
        g.dispose();
        return newImage;
    }

}

class ImageHoverButton extends JButton
{
    private class MouseHoverListener extends MouseAdapter
    {
        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent me)
        {
            opacityAnimator.changeOpacity(0.0f, 250);
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent me)
        {
            opacityAnimator.changeOpacity(1.0f, 1000);
        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me)
        {
            opacityAnimator.changeOpacity(0.5f, 50);
        }
    }

    private class OpacityAnimator
    {
        private final int DELAY_MS = 10;
        private final Timer timer;

        private float targetOpacity;
        private float currentOpacity;
        private float opacityStep;

        OpacityAnimator()
        {
            timer = new Timer(DELAY_MS, new ActionListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                {
                    if (currentOpacity > targetOpacity)
                    {
                        currentOpacity += opacityStep;
                        currentOpacity = Math.max(
                            currentOpacity, targetOpacity);
                    }
                    else if (currentOpacity < targetOpacity)
                    {
                        currentOpacity += opacityStep;
                        currentOpacity = Math.min(
                            currentOpacity, targetOpacity);
                    }
                    if (currentOpacity == targetOpacity)
                    {
                        timer.stop();
                    }
                    setOpacity(currentOpacity);
                }
            });
        }

        void changeOpacity(float targetOpacity, int durationMs)
        {
            timer.stop();
            this.targetOpacity = targetOpacity;

            float delta = targetOpacity - currentOpacity;
            if (durationMs > 0)
            {
                opacityStep = (delta / durationMs) * DELAY_MS;
            }
            else
            {
                opacityStep = delta;
            }
            timer.start();
        }
    }

    private final OpacityAnimator opacityAnimator;
    private final BufferedImage backgroundImage;
    private final BufferedImage foregroundImage;
    private float opacity = 0.0f;

    public ImageHoverButton(BufferedImage backgroundImage,
        BufferedImage foregroundImage)
    {
        this.backgroundImage = backgroundImage;
        this.foregroundImage = foregroundImage;
        this.opacityAnimator = new OpacityAnimator();
        addMouseListener(new MouseHoverListener());
        setOpaque(false);
        setBorderPainted(false);
        setRolloverEnabled(false);
        setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize()
    {
        if (super.isPreferredSizeSet())
        {
            return super.getPreferredSize();
        }
        int w = Math
            .max(backgroundImage.getWidth(), foregroundImage.getWidth());
        int h = Math.max(backgroundImage.getHeight(),
            foregroundImage.getHeight());
        return new Dimension(w, h);
    }

    public void setOpacity(float opacity)
    {
        this.opacity = opacity;
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics gr)
    {
        super.paintComponent(gr);
        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) gr;
        g.drawImage(backgroundImage, 0, 0, null);
        g.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER,
            opacity));
        g.drawImage(foregroundImage, 0, 0, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks. It is exactly what I wanted. Thanks again, if I have enough rank I will give a point for useful.

Answer (score 0):

Don't access Swing components from other threads. Use a swing Timer instead.
See [How to use swing timers](https://www.google.ch/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&ei=CzEEVKG0CLLy7Ab7qYGADQ&url=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html&cd=1&ved=0CCEQFjAA&usg=AFQjCNEHlVmY7trWixlAlCygKLrKP2-ycA&sig2=IAIw9lCvv8elzMykMSE-2Q)

Comment: True, on the one hand. On the other hand: Even when using a timer here (or just wrapping the calls that are made from the thread into a `SwingUtilities.invokeLater`) won't solve the issue. I assume it has to do with the `RescaleOp`, but *what* the actual problem is is not entirely clear.

Comment: Yes, that's true, but it might well be the EDT violation.

Comment: This awnser should rahter be a comment.

Comment: My problem and my question is not for timer or thread. But rather with `RescaleOp`. While program start, one of the `BufferedImage` opacity is 0. And It's a problem that even opacity is 0 the picture is still visible on the page. I found on the java page: [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/drawimage.html) associate with topic: Filtering Images. And there we can slide down to 0 by slider and the image completly vanish but String is still visible. And I'd like to do the same effect but with two images.